# How to use post/pre increment operators in addition problems?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

```
 main(){

    int x = 256, y = 4;
    printf("%d\n\n", x++ + ++y);   //output = 261
    printf("%d\n\n", x);          // output = 257
    printf("%d", y);              // output = 5

}
```

Is the final answer 261, because 256 -> 257 (post operator) and 5 -> 5 (pre operator) cause 256 + 5 = 261?

Comment: it is all a matter of when the variable is printed.  if preincrement, the variable is printed after the increment.  if postincrement, the variable is printed before the increment.

Comment: `main()` is incorrect. Use [`int main(void)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714) instead

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
int x = 256, y = 4;
printf("%d\n\n", x++ + ++y);
```

*In short:* The `x++` returns the value `256` and then increments `x` to 257.  The `++y` increments `y` to 5 and returns the value `5`.  The addition, therefore, adds 256 and 5 yielding `261`.

*Long windedly:* The `x++` evaluates to the current value of `x` which is `256` and schedules an increment of `x` to 257.  Similarly `++y` schedules the increment of `y` to 5 and evaluates to the incremented value `5`.  The addition, therefore, adds 256 and 5 yielding `261`.  The order in which the terms involving `x` and `y` are evaluated is not defined, but both have to be evaluated before the addition (though the increments may not be complete when the addition is evaluated).  Because there is a 'sequence point' when the arguments (and the expression denoting the function) have been evaluated but before the function is called, the increments must be complete when `printf()` is called.

The next two statements print `x` and `y` as `257` and `5`.

Note that those two `printf()` operations could be combined into one.  Neither could be combined with the first without invoking undefined behaviour.  (See [Multiple increments and undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior) for more information on this topic.)

So, allowing for the fact that I would not express it quite the way you wrote it, you seem to have the correct explanation.

Also, Standard C has required a return type on all functions for over 15 years now (since C99 was standardized).  You should write:

```
int main(void)
```

for a `main()` function that takes no arguments.  (See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for the full details.)

<sup>*Note that this question only invokes fully defined behaviour (at least, in the `printf()` statements).  It is not asking about multiple increments on a single variable between sequence points.*</sup>

Comment: Nit: `x++` *evaluates* to `256` and `++y` *evaluates* to `5`, but `x` and `y` may not be updated immediately after evaluation; the only requirement is that they be updated by the next sequence point, which is prior to the function call.  This is part of why expressions like `x++ + x++` invoke undefined behavior; the order in which the expressions are evaluated *and* the order in which the side effects are applied is unspecified, so the behavior isn't consistent.

Answer (score 1):

### It will show  UNSPECIFIED behavior

In your case, we can't tell whether x++ will be evaluated first or ++y will be evaluated first. It is compiler dependent.
So don't use expressions involving a combination of post-increment or pre-increment operators in C or C++.

For more information refer to the link:
https://www.quora.com/What-does-an-expression-involving-multiple-post-pre-decrement-increment-operators-evaluate-to-in-C-and-C++#

Comment: Actually it is not UB. While it might be undefined if x++ or ++y will be evaluated first, they do not depend on each other, so the final result is well defined

Comment: From undefined behavior, I mean we can't tell the exact answer and it is compiler dependent. Refer to the example given in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/7873716

Comment: Check the answer you linked. "it is unspecified whether x++ or y++ will be evaluated first." and "etween the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression." are the key points here. It is safe to modify x++ and y++, but UB to use x++ and ++x without sequence points

Comment: We can't tell if x++ or ++y are evaluated first, that is correct, but for the question this is actually irrelevant, as both cases lead to the same result